# Proxy iPhone node.js

Tags: javascript, iphone, node.js, proxy

I'm trying to create a real basic node.js proxy server for my iPhone. This is the code :

```
var http = require('http'), 
    request = require('request'),
    port = 8000,

    server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log("*****Proxying url : " + req.url + ", headers : " + 
    req.headers + ", method : " + req.method + ", version : " + req.httpVersion + ", statusCode : " + req.statusCode + ", socket : " + req.socket);
    request(req.url, function(error, response, body){
            for(var header in response.headers){
                res.setHeader(header, response.headers[header]);
            }
            res.write(body);
            res.end();
        });
    });

server.listen(port);
console.log("Proxy running");
```

This one works as a proxy for PC but when I run it on my iPhone, i got :

Proxy running
*****Proxying url : /, headers : [object Object], method : GET, version : 1.1, statusCode : null, socket : [object Object]

/Users/gaetanzanella/Documents/coursInfo/Tests/Node.js/Proxy/proxy.js:10
            for(var header in response.headers){
                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

Why ? Is this an Apple's protection ?

Help me please.Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you're actually running Node and the server on your iPhone, or are you just trying to visit the servers URL with your iPhone ?

Comment: Node is on my computer. I run the proxy on it. I just set the Wifi settings of my iphone to use my computer as a proxy.